# shopify theme api create theme

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am a complete noob when it comes to developing but i am trying to create my first app on shopify. Within the app I wish to create a button that when clicked installs a theme just how it is on shopify now. However, I am completely lost on how you do that.

```
POST /admin/api/2020-01/themes.json
{
  "theme": {
    "name": "Lemongrass",
    "src": "http://themes.shopify.com/theme.zip",
    "role": "main"
  }
}
```

How do I make it so when a user clicks a button a theme installs on their store. I am using node.js and react to create the app.

I have this code inside a themedownload.js file

```
const themeDownload = async (ctx, accessToken, shop) => {
  const query = JSON.stringify({
          "theme": {
            "name": "Lemongrass",
            "src": "https://codeload.github.com/Shopify/skeleton-theme/zip/master",
            "role": "unpublished"
            }
  });

  const response = await fetch(`https://${shop}/admin/api/2020-01/themes.json`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "X-Shopify-Access-Token": accessToken,
    },
    body: query
  })

  const responseJson = await response.json();
};

module.exports = themeDownload;
```

Not sure how well this would work, however, how would i then in another file create a function so when a button is clicked it will run the themedownload.js file. I do hope what I am asking/saying is making sense.

React page structure

```
const themeDownload = require('../server/themeDownload');

import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
  FormLayout,
  Layout,
  Page,
  SettingToggle,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  TextStyle,
  DisplayText,
SkeletonBodyText, SkeletonPage, Modal, TextContainer, Heading, Badge
} from '@shopify/polaris';



export default function ModalExample() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = useCallback(() => setActive(!active), [active]);

  const themeDown = useCallback(
      () => themeDownload(), 
      [],
  );

  return (
    <div style={{height: '500px'}}>
      <SkeletonPage title="Theme Library">
          <Layout>
            <Layout.Section>
              <Card sectioned>
                <Stack>
                  <Stack.Item fill>
                    <Heading>Themes</Heading>
                  </Stack.Item>
                  <Stack.Item>
                    <Button primary onClick={handleChange}>Add theme</Button>
                  </Stack.Item>
                </Stack>
              </Card>
            </Layout.Section>
          </Layout>
        </SkeletonPage>
      <Modal
        open={active}
        onClose={handleChange}
        title="Add Debutle"
        primaryAction={{
          content: 'Add to theme library',
          onAction: themeDown,
        }}
      >
        <Modal.Section>
          <TextContainer>
            <p>
              When adding theme to library, the theme will be set as unpublished.
            </p>
          </TextContainer>
        </Modal.Section>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a complicated task honestly. Working with Shopify I know how frustrating themes can be, I would start off by writing some pseudocode.

```
User clicks button, post request gets sent, app catches request, themes gets installed, configuration.
```

I would start with the button & modifying your own theme. @hat code do you have so far?

Comment: Thanks for responding I have updated my post with code I have so far

Comment: Okay lets start with making a index.html file link your JS inside the file.

Comment: i have a theme.js file which contains const themeDownload = require('../server/themeDownload'); the theme.js is basically my index.html file

Comment: Okay even better, could you show me your react app.js and project structure?

Comment: I have just added the react page structure to the post I am also not sure how to get  accessToken and shop from my server.js file